# Text file reading - Expectations of good enough?

Tags: rust

I've been rewriting a code from C to Rust and I'm stuck with how slow the reading of a "small" file is (6 million rows, 150MB, 4 columns of data). In C this file gets read in ~0.35 seconds whereas in Rust it takes 1.9 seconds on the same machine. What am I missing? Note I've compiled my code with --release. It's just a basic BufReader looping through lines.

```
// The output is wrapped in a Result to allow matching on errors.
// Returns an Iterator to the Reader of the lines of the file.
fn read_lines<P>(filename: P) -> io::Result<io::Lines<io::BufReader<File>>>
where P: AsRef<Path>, {
    let file = File::open(filename)?;
    Ok(io::BufReader::new(file).lines())
}

fn main() {
    // File hosts.txt must exist in the current path
    let start = Instant::now();
    let started_assigning = start.elapsed();

    let mut count = 0;
    if let Ok(lines) = read_lines("./data_summary_6m.csv") {
        // Consumes the iterator, returns an (Optional) String
        for line in lines.flatten() {
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    let finished_assigning = start.elapsed();

    println!("{:?}, Run time\n", finished_assigning - started_assigning);
    println!("{:?}, Counted rows\n", count);

}
```

And the output is:

```
1.898065676s, Run time
6000001, Counted rows
```

I've read through all the threads on StackOverflow, implemented the BufReader one, checked some examples and tutorials and the serde implementation.

### Update

I've followed the suggestion to use read_line and the speed up is significant, dropping to 500ms of runtime to loop through everything. However, reading the lines within the loop now takes much more, mainly becuse of the split and the iterators

```
let file = File::open("./data_summary_60m.csv")?;
let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);
let mut string = String::new();
while reader.read_line(&mut string)? > 0 {
    let mut line = string.split(",");
    let col1 =  line.next(); 
    let col2 =  line.next(); 
    let col3 =  line.next(); 
    let col4 =  line.next(); 
}
```

### Update 2

For all Rust rookies out there, remember you need to build and run your code in --release mode. Building it with flag -r won't cut. Do:

```
cargo build -r
```

Followed by:

```
cargo run -r
```

Comment: Try to use `','` (a `char`) instead of `","` (a `&str`) in split, it should be simpler to detect.

Comment: No difference with that

Comment: As stated by Masklinn in its comment, you have to use `string.clear()` at the end of each loop. Without that, it will always grow, since `.read_line()` appends to the existing buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my investigation around this topic.
Actually, I observe something different from what is reported in the question, i.e. the Rust version runs faster than the C version in similar conditions.

First, we have to consider that your C version (not shown in the question) is probably different from what Rust does because in C a `char` is simply a byte, while in Rust a `char` could be described by a multibyte sequence.
Thus, iterating through the `char`s in order to detect `\n` or `,` in both languages is not equivalent because Rust has to do more work at each byte in order to check whether it is a multibyte sequence or not.
For this reason, in Rust we should use a `Vec<u8>` instead of a `String` as line buffer, to match more closely what is done in C.

Here is the data file I used.

```bash
$ head -3 data_summary_6m.csv ; tail -3 data_summary_6m.csv
header 1,header 2,header 3,header 4
row 1 col 1,row 1 col 2,row 1 col 3,row 1 col 4
row 2 col 1,row 2 col 2,row 2 col 3,row 2 col 4
row 5999998 col 1,row 5999998 col 2,row 5999998 col 3,row 5999998 col 4
row 5999999 col 1,row 5999999 col 2,row 5999999 col 3,row 5999999 col 4
row 6000000 col 1,row 6000000 col 2,row 6000000 col 3,row 6000000 col 4
$ du -m data_summary_6m.csv
408     data_summary_6m.csv
```

Here is the Rust program I used.

```rust
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{BufRead, BufReader},
    time::Instant,
};

fn main() {
    const FILENAME: &str = "data_summary_6m.csv";
    const BYTES: bool = true;
    const FIELDS: bool = true;

    let start = Instant::now();
    let mut input = BufReader::new(File::open(FILENAME).unwrap());
    let mut row_count = 0;
    let mut field_count = 0;
    if BYTES {
        let mut buf = Vec::new();
        while input.read_until(b'\n', &mut buf).unwrap() != 0 {
            if FIELDS {
                for _field in buf.split(|b| *b == b',') {
                    field_count += 1;
                }
            }
            row_count += 1;
            buf.clear();
        }
    } else {
        let mut buf = String::new();
        while input.read_line(&mut buf).unwrap() != 0 {
            if FIELDS {
                for _field in buf.split(',') {
                    field_count += 1;
                }
            }
            row_count += 1;
            buf.clear();
        }
    }
    let elapsed = start.elapsed();

    println!(
        "BYTES={}, FIELDS={}, {:?}, {} rows, {} fields",
        BYTES, FIELDS, elapsed, row_count, field_count
    );
}
```

On a quite good computer, on Linux, I obtain these average results.

```
BYTES=false, FIELDS=true,  263.554607ms, 6000001 rows, 24000004 fields
BYTES=false, FIELDS=false, 110.068005ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields
BYTES=true,  FIELDS=true,  231.297859ms, 6000001 rows, 24000004 fields
BYTES=true,  FIELDS=false,  75.568951ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields
$ echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
BYTES=true,  FIELDS=false, 302.114161ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields
```

We can see that working with bytes instead of `char`s helps significantly.
Of course, if the data file is not cached, the performances are ruined.

On the same computer, with WSL on Windows11, it's quite similar, except when the data file is not cached (much worse).

```
BYTES=false, FIELDS=true,  262.737868ms, 6000001 rows, 24000004 fields
BYTES=false, FIELDS=false, 116.33532ms,  6000001 rows, 0 fields
BYTES=true,  FIELDS=true,  238.555221ms, 6000001 rows, 24000004 fields
BYTES=true,  FIELDS=false,  75.734409ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields
$ echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
BYTES=true,  FIELDS=false, 529.233063ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields
```

On the same computer running natively on Windows11, it becomes quite worse, but we still have a significant difference between bytes and `char`s.

```
BYTES=false, FIELDS=true,  408.2316ms, 6000001 rows, 24000004 fields
BYTES=false, FIELDS=false, 264.1243ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields
BYTES=true,  FIELDS=true,  388.721ms,  6000001 rows, 24000004 fields
BYTES=true,  FIELDS=false, 217.6963ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields
```

On a much older computer, with a slow disk, I obtain these results on Linux.

```
BYTES=false, FIELDS=true,  465.829884ms, 6000001 rows, 24000004 fields
BYTES=false, FIELDS=false, 220.464719ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields
BYTES=true,  FIELDS=true,  420.407204ms, 6000001 rows, 24000004 fields
BYTES=true,  FIELDS=false, 187.218659ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields
$ echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
BYTES=true,  FIELDS=false,  4.01890092s, 6000001 rows, 0 fields
```

We still have the difference between bytes and `char`s, but the uncached situation is much worse.

All of this was compiled with `--release` and Rust 1.75.0.

I decided to investigate the C version; here is the program I used.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

double
now(void) {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (double)tv.tv_sec+1e-6*(double)tv.tv_usec;
}

int
main(void) {
    const char *FILENAME="data_summary_6m.csv";
    const bool FIELDS=false;
    const double start=now();
    FILE *input=fopen(FILENAME, "rb");
    // ptrace shows reads of 8192 bytes in Rust and 4096 in C,
    // then we provide the same buffer size
    // (however, this does not significantly change the performance)
    char input_buffer[8192];
    setvbuf(input, input_buffer, _IOFBF, sizeof(input_buffer));
    //
    int row_count=0;
    int field_count=0;
    char buf[0x100];
    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), input)!=NULL) {
        if(FIELDS) {
            for(const char *begin=buf; begin!=NULL; ) {
                const char *found=strchr(begin, ',');
                ++field_count;
                begin=found+!!found;
            }
        }
        ++row_count;
    }
    fclose(input);
    const double elapsed=1e3*(now()-start);
    printf("FIELDS=%s, %gms, %d rows, %d fields\n",
        FIELDS ? "true" : "false", elapsed, row_count, field_count);
    return 0;
}
```

It was compiled with gcc 13.2.1 like this.

```
  gcc -std=c99 -o prog_c prog_c.c \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
      -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wvla \
      -O3 -DNDEBUG -march=native
```

On the same *quite good* computer, on Linux, I obtained

```
FIELDS=true,  210.064ms, 6000001 rows, 24000004 fields
FIELDS=false, 113.162ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields
$ echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
FIELDS=false, 271.223ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields
```

and on the same *quite old* computer, on Linux, I got

```
FIELDS=true,  435.273ms, 6000001 rows, 24000004 fields
FIELDS=false, 261.561ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields
$ echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
FIELDS=false, 3970.08ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields
```

(I didn't bother switching to Windows)
With `ptrace` I saw that Rust made reads of 8192 bytes instead of 4096 for C (initially); however, adapting the buffer size on the C side did not change the results so much.

Here we can see that the performance is worse with C than with Rust when we only split lines.
*quite good* computer: 113ms in C vs 75ms in Rust
*quite old* computer: 261ms in C vs 187ms in Rust
I simply *guess* that the algorithms in `fgets()` and `.read_until()` are quite different (vectorised or not for example) but I didn't check.
On the other hand, when it comes to splitting in columns, the results are quite similar.
*quite good* computer: 210ms in C vs 231ms in Rust
*quite old* computer: 435ms in C vs 420ms in Rust

(all these micro-benchmarks were run many times in order to retain only stable average results).

Comment: Nicee! Thank you so much. I re-created the same dataset as you (it has 472MB) and ran you code on my machine (A 2021 MacBookPro with an M1 chip,  32GB of RAM and 500 GB SSD). Running Rust:
`BYTES=true, FIELDS=true, 4.371883375s, 6000001 rows, 24000004 fields

BYTES=false, FIELDS=false, 514.242125ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields
BYTES=true, FIELDS=false, 386.661375ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields
BYTES=false, FIELDS=true, 2.147387459s, 6000001 rows, 24000004 fields`

Running the C program:
`FIELDS=false, 224.163ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields

FIELDS=true, 293.068ms, 6000001 rows, 24000004 fields`

Comment: Aaaaa damn it. I just realized it what's wrong. I've been building my program with --release but I haven't been running it with --release. I wasn't aware I should do `cargo run -r`, I was doing `cargo build -r` followed by `cargo run`. Thank you so much for your time and patience today, kind stranger :-)

Comment: @kkrapic Aaaah thank you for this final explanation. I couldn't understand how the performances could vary so dramatically from one system to another. Could you publish the `--release` performances then? I'm just curious.

Comment: Certainly, fresh numbers below and very similar to C. Thanks again! 

`BYTES=false, FIELDS=true, 348.650417ms, 6000001 rows, 24000004 fields;

BYTES=true, FIELDS=false, 137.649375ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields;

BYTES=true, FIELDS=true, 311.452375ms, 6000001 rows, 24000004 fields;

BYTES=false, FIELDS=false, 153.615583ms, 6000001 rows, 0 fields`

Answer (score 3):

What does the C code look like?

If you look at [the documentation of `BufRead::lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) you can see:

> yield instances of `io::Result<String>`

so this is a convenient iterator, but once which allocates a string per line, and thus not exactly *efficient* as you're allocating 6 million buffers you're not using. Especially if you're using the system allocator (which I assume you are).

If you're not allocating a string per line in C, you're comparing rather different situations. In that case you probably want [`BufRead::read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) instead.

Comment: You're right - read_line drops the runtime to 500ms. However, doing operations within a line, mainly string.split(',') and then each call of iterator .next() adds another 300ms, ending up with 2.2s. Any trick there?

Comment: @kkrapic how do you use this `.split()`? I cannot reproduce such a slowdown after using `.read_line()`

Comment: I've pasted the updated code in the body of the question, also to direct people towards the answer. It's a basic .split(), this is what I find surprising.

Comment: @kkrapic I don't think that should affect a `split`'s speed (as it should be lazy, and 150MB should well fit into memory) but `read_line` will append the new content to the buffer, so you need to `clear()` the string at the end of each iteration otherwise the buffer keeps growing, and you keep processing just the start of it.

Answer (score 3):

`.lines()` gives you an iteator of `io::Result<String>`.  Recall that `String` is an owned, heap-allocated sequence of bytes (which must be valid UTF-8).

Note that your code *never uses the string* which means every line is going to result in a heap allocation, a copy of data from the read buffer into that allocation, and then a deallocation, all of which is completely unnecessary.  Heap allocations are pretty expensive, so doing this for each line is going to add up quickly.  (And I assume your C code is not doing a `malloc`+`free` for each line.)

Instead, read into a byte buffer and just count the `b'\n'` characters.  This will require no heap allocations whatsoever.

On my machine, with a 578MB file of random text data of 6m lines, and the data primed in the I/O cache, your code takes about 350ms to run.

This code takes about 135ms on the same data:

```
fn main() {
    // File hosts.txt must exist in the current path
    let start = Instant::now();
    let started_assigning = start.elapsed();

    let mut count = 0;
    let mut file = File::open("./data_summary_6m.csv").expect("failed to open file");
    let mut buffer = [0u8; 8 * 1024]; // 8kb read buffer

    loop {
        let bytes = file.read(&mut buffer).expect("read failed");
        if bytes == 0 {
            break;
        }

        for &i in &buffer[0..bytes] {
            if i == b'\n' {
                count += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    let finished_assigning = start.elapsed();

    println!("{:?}, Run time\n", finished_assigning - started_assigning);
    println!("{:?}, Counted rows\n", count);
}
```

I can get the runtime down a bit further to 120ms by increasing the size of the read buffer to 32kb, so also keep in mind that buffer size can matter.  A larger buffer means fewer read calls to the system.

Comment: a somewhat simpler / less low level version would be to use `read_line`, it's a bit less efficient because it does double buffer but it's usually a better fit for line processing as you should not need to handle e.g. the line being larger than your buffer, or reconciling partial lines, etc...

Comment: @Masklinn If you are going to actually use the text data on each line, yes. If you are just counting the number of lines, that's still extra work for no real benefit.

Comment: sure but if you're micro-optimising line counting then you might be better off mmapping the file and running your search, probably parallelised as well